# Web parts on Blank Web Part Page are in a single column instead of the layout they're supposed to be in

Tags: web-part

Let's see if I can explain this correctly... I just created a new Blank Web Part Page that I intend to use as my homepage. The layout is supposed to have a header, top left, top right, center left, center, center right, footer, and right section. No matter where I put a web part, it's stacking it on top of each other instead of side by side. Am I doing something wrong or is there a setting off somewhere? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can provide an answer just yet, but here are a few clarifying questions that should help get us there:

1. While in edit mode, do you see the layout displaying like you want?
2. Assuming you see the layout correctly, can you try and drag and drop a webpart to a different zone, and does it stick?
3. Have you tried editing the properties of the webpart and changing its zone in the layout section, and seeing if that sticks?
4. Have you tried changing the layout of the page and seeing if the issue occurs on all layouts?
5. What browser are you using, and have you tried using a different browser?
6. Do you have any custom css or js in play, either through a custom master page, custom css layout, webpart etc...? If so, that could also be affecting the page.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

No, the layout in edit mode is just stacked on top of each other in rows. It's not layed out the way it's supposed to be. Yes, I've tried editing the properties and changing the zones, nothing. All the other layouts seem to work just fine, it's just this one. Yes, I've tried it in both IE and Chrome. I did have custom CSS, which I thought could be affecting it, but I created a new test page, without the CSS, with the same layout, and it still does the same thing.

I wasn't sure if this was a known issue with this particular layout or not. My company just migrated to SP2016 and they've been having issues with the migration, so I'm wondering if this is one of them. (if it's not already a known SP-wide issue)